# How to reset OnTouchListener?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a custom object which also extends `View.OnTouchListener`. It uses `onTouch` events to be dragged around. Whenever this custom object detects a collision with a target object, it fires up custom event. Upon receiving this event, `MainActivity` uses public method of that custom object to start animation, which moves custom object to initial position. In the `onAnimationStart` of `AnimatorSet`, `OnTouchListener` is set to `null` and in the `onAnimationEnd` that custom object is again assigned with `OnTouchListener` - this is the culprit of malfunction, which is as follows.
I touch custom view and drag my finger to target object, but I dont release my finger when animation of return to initial position starts and keep dragging it around target object. The custom view returns to initial position, but then re-appears at touched position and returns to initial position and this repeats again and again.

I tried breaking the MOVE event, returning "true" to consume the event, but nothing helps. How do I release/reset new `onTouchListener` from previous touch?

onTouch code (in MyCustomObject class):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                //moves view's center to the click location

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                //returns view to initial position

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                //moves the view at the center of touch -- dragging function

                //checks for collision 
                if (collission occured) {

                        //trigger event
                        listener.myEvent((MyCustomObject) view);

                }

                break;
            }

        }

        //does not consume touch
        return true;

    }
```

Event handling code (in MainActivity class):

```
    MyCustomObject.EventsListener listener = new MyCustomObject.EventsListener() {
            @Override
            public void MyEvent(MyCustomObject submittedObject) {

                 //some code to decide if return to initial position should occur

                 //return custom object to initial position
                 submittedObject.returnToInitPosition(submittedObject);

                }

            }
```

Code of returnToInitPosition() (in MyCustomObject class):

```
public void returnToInitPosition(final View view) {

    //return to initial position animation
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(---my anims---);

    //temporary remove of onTouch listener
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationStart(animation);

            //remove listener on animation start
            view.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

            //re-add listener on animation complete
            view.setOnTouchListener(MyCustomObject.this);
        }

    });

    //start animation
    set.start();

}
```

Comment: I also tried to dispatch ACTION_UP event from animation end hopping it would break the dragging.

Comment: Also tried using `view.setEnabled(false);` and `view.setEnabled(true);` in Animation states, but all works the same, previous gesture is continued.

Comment: Not really clear, what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking how to ensure, that my CustomObject would stay in place after collision event and I would need to touch it anew in order to drag it again. In other words I need to simulate releasing of the finger on event fired even if user continues to drag his finger.

Comment: I even tried to use Runnable and Handler to re-assign OnTouchListener after 1 second, but if I keep dragging my finger for longer than 1 second, my Custom object still reacts to previous gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by assigning another touch listener on animation start. This another custom touch listener ignores all other events except ACTION_UP (this way current gesture is ended). Upon detecting this action, original touch listener is re-assigned.